Warning: "React does not recognize the `fetchPriority` prop on a DOM element."
I recently upgraded to the latest versions of React and Next.js and am getting the following error:
Warning: React does not recognize the `fetchPriority` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `fetchpriority` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
    at img
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/image-component.js:136:11)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/image-component.js:245:47)
    at a
    at LinkComponent (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/link.js:110:19)

I've read an issue on the GitHub repo, but the only solution appeared to be installing the canary version which I'd prefer not to do in production.
What would be a good way to get rid of this issue without upgrading to the canary build?

There was another solution in the github discussion, that this issue is caused by React 18.3.1, so rolling back to 18.2.0 fixes this, and Next is not dependent on 18.3.1.

You could just rollback React version to 18.2.0. However, you could also try upgrading to React 19, possibly that error message is removed there.
GitHub discussion regarding this fetchPriority error
UPDATE: This issue has been fixed by upgrading from next@14.2.3 to next@14.2.4

I updated to next@14.2.5 at the time of reading this and it's fixed.

Upgrade to 14.2.5 is solve this issue

Before:
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^2.0.4",
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.1.3",
    "@rainbow-me/rainbowkit": "2",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^5.44.0",
    "ethers": "^6.13.0",
    "next": "14.2.3",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "sharp": "^0.33.4",
    "viem": "2.x",
    "wagmi": "2"
  },

what worked for my next js project is removing ^ in "react": "^18.1.0"
Found through https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/65161 discussion

Wow, this worked for me! I was actually getting the error with 18.2.0 but by removing the ^ the warning disappeared.

Looking for a fix from various repository, because the issue is only with jest, for the moment i use --silent CLI option with jest.
So, test command is npx jest --silent
